# How to insert data from a HTML Select Form into a SQL Database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have some code with a HTML Select Form. How can I insert this into a MySQL Database? Who can help my?

## THE FORM

```
<select name="fileCategory">
    <?php

    $sqlCategorieen = mysqli_query($MySQL, "SELECT * FROM `categorieen`");
    foreach($sqlCategorieen AS $sqlCategorieData) {
        echo '<option value="'.$sqlCategorieData['categorieId'].'">'.$sqlCategorieData['categorieNaam'].'</option>';
    }

    ?>
</select>
```

## THE MYSQLI_QUERY

```
$sqlUpdateBestanden = mysqli_query($MySQL, "UPDATE `bestanden` SET `bestandTitel` = '".$bestandTitel."' `bestandCategorieId` = '".$bestandCategorieId."' WHERE `bestandId` = ".$_GET['file']."");
if($sqlUpdateBestanden) {
    echo 'Opslaan Gelukt!';
    header('refresh:1');
} else {
    echo 'Opslaan Niet Gelukt!';
}
```

Who can help my with this problem? Thank you!

*Sorry for my English! It's so bad! Sorry!*

Comment: Pleassse research SQL injections. This is open to them. Please explain which variable is the `select` value, and how the form is processed. Perhaps `fileCategory` doesn't equal `file`?

Comment: I'll advice you to read up on PDO. Here's a good read. https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#dml